# Derivation of tau time-stepping in Gillespie algorithm?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, monte-carlo, simulation

I'm trying to find the derivation of tau ($\tau$) in the Gillespie algorithm.  All the papers and chapters I've found simply say, without actually showing its derivation: "Tau is given by"

**$\tau = \frac{1}{a_0(X_t)}ln\frac{1}{r_1}$**

*where $a_0$ is the propensity function, $X_t$ is the state vector and $r_1$ is one of two random numbers from the uniform distribution [0,1].*

Specifically, I want to know where the **$ln \frac{1}{r_1}$** comes from.

Does anybody know a good source where this is explained please?

Comment: This is an approximation of an exponential distribution. The following paper by Daniel Gillespie himself provides an excellent introduction: Gillespie DT. Stochastic simulation of chemical kinetics. Annu Rev Phys Chem. 2007;58:35-55. doi: 10.1146/annurev.physchem.58.032806.104637. PMID: 17037977. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17037977/

Answer (score 1):

The (or at least, one) derivation of tau is from interarrival times in a Poisson distribution. See, for example, chapter 5 (specifically, section 5.3.3 in the Ninth Edition) of Sheldon Ross's classic statistics text "Introduction to Probability Models."